# how to transform data in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db={
  setting: [
    {
      "_id": "5fce2865cf6b771054133981",
      "files": [
        {
          "_id": "5fc09a5c1027307146d5ede5",
          "imageUrl": "xyz.jpg",
          "width": 375,
          "height": 500,
          "videoUrl": "video.mp4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fcdcc60da26c80a6de06759",
      "files": [
        {
          "_id": "5fc09a5c1027307146d5ede5",
          "imageUrl": "xyz.jpg",
          "width": 375,
          "height": 500             
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fcdcc52da26c80a6de06758",
      "files": []
    }
  ]
}

db.setting.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      files: 1
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/KBOCksJ5xzu

wondering how to get data if array exists imageUrl and videoUrl.

I need seperate data if i request for imageUrl it should return only those record that have imageurl with some data if i request videoUrl it should return that records consists of videoUrl

how to achieve this please guide

Thanks

Comment: not clear question, you want something like this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WNPu1zKbYMV)?

Comment: @turivishal Thanks for clue it is not happening in my mind thank you

Comment: Could you include the expected output? `db.setting.find([ { "files.videoUrl": { $exists: true } } ])` this and it's imageUrl equivalent would only return those that contain the field in the files subobjects.